# VBA Create and Rename Tables

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, listobject, excel-tables

I'm looking to create a table without selecting the first row and creating a table. Then naming the table based on what the sheet name is.

```
Sub ConvertDataToTables()
 
'  For i = 3 To 5
'    Sheets(i).Activate
'    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
'  Next i
  
  For i = 3 To 5
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(i).Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Cells.AutoFilter
    Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Select
    If ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Count < 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add.Name = ActiveSheet.Name
    End If
  Next i
```

Table names get place with an underscore with a space and I don't want that. so Sum Day = Sum_Day from my code. I also want to have the selection not choose the top row but everything below.

Comment: A table name cannot contain a space. What's your alternative instead of the underscore? Do you have a list of the worksheet names instead of their unreliable indexes?

Comment: @VBasic2008 renaming sheet name and table name without spaces

Comment: Do you mean if the worksheet name is `data sheet`, rename both to `DataSheet`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes

Comment: If it is only for the blanks: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add.Name = Replace(ActiveSheet.Name, " ", "")`.  You should, btw, learn how to avoid using `Select` and `Activate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Convert Table to Excel Table (`ListObject`)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertDataToTables()
 
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const FIRST_INDEX As Long = 3
    Const LAST_INDEX As Long = 5
     
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, fCell As Range, lo As ListObject
    Dim i As Long, NewName As String
    
    For i = FIRST_INDEX To LAST_INDEX
        
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(i)
        
        If ws.ListObjects.Count = 0 Then

            ' Remove the auto filter.
            If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
            
            NewName = Replace(Application.Proper(ws.Name), " ", "")
            ws.Name = NewName
            
            Set fCell = ws.Range(FIRST_CELL)
            With fCell.CurrentRegion
                Set rg = fCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - fCell.Row, _
                    .Column + .Columns.Count - fCell.Column)
            End With
            
            Set lo = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rg, , xlYes)
            lo.Name = NewName
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I had it working with this before however I didn't save it after edits. I have been getting this error, "This will change a filtered range on your worksheet. To complete this task, please remove AutoFilter." at Set lo = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rg, , xlYes)

Comment: Below the line `If ws.FilterMode...`, add the line `If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False`. This happens when the initial filtered range is different than the table range.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code. It will replace spaces from the sheet names. Also, it doesn't use `Select` to rely on the ActiveSheet - for further reading refer to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

The code uses intermediate Range variables to define the range for the table. It starts at cell A2 (`startCell`) and uses the last cell of the `CurrentRegion` as `endCell`.

```
Dim sheetIndex As Long
For sheetIndex = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetIndex)
        If .ListObjects.Count = 0 Then
            Dim startcell As Range, endCell As Range, tableRange As Range
            Set startcell = .Cells(2, 1)
            Set endCell = startcell.CurrentRegion.Cells(startcell.CurrentRegion.Cells.Count)
            Set tableRange = .Range(startcell, endCell)
            Debug.Print tableRange.Address
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tableRange).Name = Replace(.Name, " ", "")
        End If
    End With
Next sheetIndex
```

Note that you should **always** use `Option Explicit` and declare all Variables and you should **never** use `On Error Resume Next` except for single statement where you know that they might fail (and you want to do the error handling by your own).